# My computer boots into black screen after hard shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2

This is my first time doing anything like this but I really need my computer back so it here goes. The other day my computer froze so I had to unplug it and replug it however after I did so instead of going to the login screen  I had this pink screen with the words GNU GRUB at the top and with the three options:

`Advanced options for Ubuntu`

`Memory test (memtest86)`

`Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)`

And if I don't click any of them in time it goes to this strange screen with a ton of numbers on it and I could not get out of that screen unless I unplug. Please help me if you can I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you please edit your title to make it more useful? Please also provide screenshots of what you see, otherwise we have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @muru the complete edit was made by me, this is totally wrong on your part

Comment: @rancho what was?

Comment: Edit to this question, but you took the credit

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live usb

Go to terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
sudo reboot
```

Now try normal login. Hopefully everything will work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu", and hopefully you should see a selection of older Ubuntu kernels. Select the newest version. If you're able to boot, open a terminal window and type: sudo update-grub, then enter your password. Reboot the computer, and you might be fine again.